# 3 internet line in a single network

Tags: networking, mikrotik

i'm going to bond 3 internet line in a single network.
i'm using Mikrotik RB750 router, I configured this router like this:

```
/ip firewall mangle
add chain=input in-interface=WAN2 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN2_conn
add chain=input in-interface=WAN3 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN3_conn
add chain=input in-interface=WAN4 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN4_conn
add chain=input in-interface=WAN5 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN5_conn

add chain=output connection-mark=WAN2_conn action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN2
add chain=output connection-mark=WAN3_conn action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN3
add chain=output connection-mark=WAN4_conn action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN4
add chain=output connection-mark=WAN5_conn action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN5

add chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.2.0/24 action=accept in-interface=bridge1
add chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.3.0/24 action=accept in-interface=bridge1
add chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.4.0/24 action=accept in-interface=bridge1
add chain=prerouting dst-address=192.168.5.0/24 action=accept in-interface=bridge1

add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/0 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN2_conn passthrough=yes 
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/1 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN3_conn passthrough=yes
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/2 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN4_conn passthrough=yes 
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/3 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN5_conn passthrough=yes

add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN2_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN2
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN3_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN3
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN4_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN4
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN5_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN5

/ip route
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.2.1 routing-mark=to_WAN2 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.3.1 routing-mark=to_WAN3 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.4.1 routing-mark=to_WAN4 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.5.1 routing-mark=to_WAN5 check-gateway=ping

add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.2.1 distance=1 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.3.1 distance=2 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.4.1 distance=2 check-gateway=ping
add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.5.1 distance=2 check-gateway=ping

/ip firewall nat
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN2 action=masquerade
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN3 action=masquerade
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN4 action=masquerade
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN5 action=masquerade
```

Note: The router has 5 physiccal ports (WAN1,WAN2,WAN3,WAN4,WAN5) and 1 wireless port. WAN1 and Wireless port connected together via `Bridge1` and all of the nodes in the network connected to Bridge1 (WAN1 or Wireless), now there is no problem in internet bonding, and it's working fine. but when a node in this network wants to visit a website (for example: google.com), the request will send to google.com from all of the internet lines! so for each nodes we are sending 2 more request to a single website!
I want to divide these internet lines between network nodes, for example each rang of IP use a specific Internet line, like this:

```
192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.64: Use first Internet line 
192.168.1.65 - 192.168.1.128: Use second Internet line 
192.168.1.129 - 192.168.1.254: Use third Internet line
```

is it possible? can you help me?

Comment: Where exactly do you do bonding? I think you are confused with the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use PCC (Per connection Classifier) but what you ask is load balancing based on the source IP address range.

Remove the following rules from your configuration:

```
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/0 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN2_conn passthrough=yes 
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/1 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN3_conn passthrough=yes
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/2 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN4_conn passthrough=yes 
add chain=prerouting dst-address-type=!local in-interface=bridge1 per-connection-classifier=both-addresses-and-ports:4/3 action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=WAN5_conn passthrough=yes

add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN2_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN2
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN3_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN3
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN4_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN4
add chain=prerouting connection-mark=WAN5_conn in-interface=bridge1 action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_WAN5
```

And add the following:

```
add chain=prerouting src-address=192.168.1.0/26 in-interface=bridge1 dst-address=!192.168.1.0/24 action=mark-routing disabled=no new-routing-mark=to_WAN2 passthrough=no 
add chain=prerouting src-address=192.168.1.64/26 in-interface=bridge1 dst-address=!192.168.1.0/24 action=mark-routing disabled=no new-routing-mark=to_WAN3 passthrough=no 
add chain=prerouting src-address=192.168.1.128/25 in-interface=bridge1 dst-address=!192.168.1.0/24 action=mark-routing disabled=no new-routing-mark=to_WAN4 passthrough=no
```

There is no need to mark the connections and then route-mark after. You can route-mark directly based on the source address range.